# Trying to add objects inside empty NSMutableArray at different indices in iOS

Tags: nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an application where I am working with an array of words, and each word needs to be in a particular index of the array.  I have another array that holds the corresponding indices for each word.  When I iterate through the first array, and try to add the word to the second array in the index found in the index array, I am getting the following runtime exception:

> 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'

My code is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [wordList count]; i++) {

        [wordTypeList insertObject:[wordList objectAtIndex:i] atIndex:[[sort objectAtIndex:i] intValue]];
    }
```

Where wordList is my initial array, sort is the array that holds numbers that represent the indices for each word, and wordTypeList is the second array that is holding the array in the correct order.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is `wordTypeList` even initialized? Also, why don't you just sort the `wordList` instead?

Comment: WordTypeList is initialized but how would I sort the wordList according to the indices inside the sort array?

Comment: In your `wordList` array, remove the object by calling `removeObject`, and then insert the object back into `wordList` by calling `insetObjectAtIndex` at the index in `sort`.

Comment: What would happen to the word whose index it would be taking over?

Comment: Nothing. It insert's the object at that index, so the index of the objects after that one get increased by 1. Try it yourself!